# Convert IDictionary<Guid,string> to the IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How i can convert `IDictionary<Guid,string>` to the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`?
I want to use string as `SelectListItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the guid as the value, you can use

```
dictionary.Select(x => new SelectListItem  { Text = x.Value, Value = x.Key })
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you *could* just use

```
dictionary.Values().Select(x => new SelectedListItem { Text = x })
```

Just be aware that it may not be in a useful order: `Dictionary<,>` is inherently unordered (or rather, the order may change and shouldn't be relied on).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
var selectList = dictionary
    .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value) // Order the Select List by the dictionary value
    .Select(kvp => new SelectListItem
    {
        Selected = kvp.Key == model.SelectedGuid, // optional but would allow you to maintain the selection when re-displaying the view
        Text = kvp.Value,
        Value = kvp.Key
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ, you could do something like,

```
var theSelectList = from dictItem in dict
                    select new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = dictItem.Value,
                        Value = dictItem.Key.ToString()
                    };
```